# Что такое CLI (c++/CLI)?

Tags: c++-cli

Читал, это как то связано с .net. А что это вообще такое, как работает и зачем нужно? И как это отключить (слышал есть такое) в visual studio 2010?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать по-буржуйски я не гу-гу

Comment: Как я знаю, то CLI - это command line interface. То есть командная строка

Comment: Вообще-то в левой части страницы и на русский ссылка есть: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

Comment: @TAPAHbl4, уважение у вас прямо таки "зашкаливает" =D. Если не уверены, пишите хотя бы в комментариях.

Answer (score 6):

CLI в данном случае не командная строка, а Common Language Infrastructure, то есть, говоря языком Пушкина и Достоевского, Общеязыковая Инфраструктура. CLI  не что иное, как спецификация, в которой описывается архитектура .NET и связанных с ним проектов (в частности, Mono) C++/CLI не что иное, как управляемый С++, код которого транслируется в CIL   ( не путать с CLI), представляющий собой что-то вроде ассемблера для .net